What is the optimal number of samples in a random forest classification?
I am conducting a supervised classification as part of a LULC analysis. I have 8 classes with sample sizes maxing at 500. However, I am still seeing some misclassification and want to add more classes, but I am concerned about overfitting. I am not a statistician. Does anyone know the optimal number of samples for a 8-class random forest classification?

Welcome to GIS SE.  This is a problem solving site rather a discussion forum. The type of question you have asked is of opinion-based. You can search google or review literature to know about the issue.
